# JavaFX + FXML progress bar not progressing?

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar, javafx-8

I am in trouble with my `ProgressBar` in my JavaFX app fueled with FXML configuration.

Or I'd rather say, I have never programmed a REAL progress bar in JavaFX, just one fake in Swing during my studies.

So I have a `Controller`, inside this controller I have:

```
@FXML
ProgressBar progressBar;
```

then I have a method:

```
@FXML
private void handleCommand() {
    if (handlePasswordField()) {
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setProgress(10);
        handleDocker(CMD + DOCKER_MYSQL_PULL, APPLICATION_NAME);
        progressBar.setProgress(50);
        handleDocker(CMD + DOCKER_MYSQL_RUN + rootPassword + DOCKER_MYSQL_RUN_SUFFIX, APPLICATION_NAME);
        progressBar.setProgress(100);
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

the `handleDocker()` method:

```
private void handleDocker(String command, String applicationName) {
    AppUtility.runWindowsCommand(command, applicationName);
}
```

and `AppUtility.runWindowsCommand()`:

```
public static void runWindowsCommand(String command, String applicationName) {
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println(applicationName + process.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String sout;
        while ((sout = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(applicationName + sout);
        }                   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And finally, this may be something that could help building the progress bar, sample console output of `runWindowsCommand()` method:

```
DOCKER: java.io.BufferedOutputStream@6fda88a4
DOCKER: Using default tag: latest
DOCKER: latest: Pulling from library/mysql
DOCKER: Digest: sha256:a571337738c9205427c80748e165eca88edc5a1157f8b8d545fa127fc3e29269
DOCKER: Status: Image is up to date for mysql:latest
DOCKER: java.io.BufferedOutputStream@227fe897
```

I am assuming that my approach to this is terribly wrong... but I have read many stuff about the `ProgressBar`, here on StackOverflow and in the internet generally, and I haven't found any answer how should I make the progress bar progress... And how to do it properly...

Comment: You appear to be doing all the work on the _JavaFX Application Thread_. The `ProgressBar` can't render updates until a ["pulse"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438) occurs, which can't happen if the FX thread is busy doing something else. You should run the work on a background thread using a [`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). You would update the `progress` property of the `Task` and bind the `ProgressBar` to it.

Comment: @Slaw - thanks for Your comment, I was researching the Task topic while You wrote, so I went this way and it is actually working very fine :)